# Unable to locate the dependencies while resolving the xray Violations

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to find the dependencies in maven project using the command

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep dependencyname
```

I am able to see the dependency ie

```
[INFO] | +-dependencygroupId:dependencyartifactId:jar:2.2.0.0:compile
```

but I am unable to find the same in any of the pom.xml nor in any file search inside the project.
Can some one tell me how to resolve this

Comment: It's probably a dependency of a dependency (of a dependency, etc).

Comment: Found it . I did a maven dependency:tree and was able to locate the dependency inside a dependency